# why does jquery display the error function?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, cordova

I'm trying to retrieve multiple JSON data from my online PHP for my Cordova app. I'm using jquery for this. It keeps displaying the error code.
This is the online php I'm retrieving from https://orba.com.ng/getemployees.php

```
  localStorage['serviceURL'] = "http://orba.com.ng/";
  var serviceURL = localStorage['serviceURL'];
  var scroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {
      vScrollbar: false,
      hScrollbar: false,
      hScroll: false
  });

  var employees;

  $(window).load(function() {
      setTimeout(getEmployeeList, 100);
  });

  $(document).ajaxError(function(event, request, settings) {
      $('#busy').hide();
      alert("Error accessing the server");
  });

  function getEmployeeList() {
      $('#busy').show();
      $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getemployees.php', function(data) {
          $('#busy').hide();
          $('#employeeList li').remove();
          employees = data.items;
          $.each(employees, function(index, employee) {
              $('#employeeList').append('<li><a href="employeedetails.html?id=' + employee.id + '">' +
                  '<img src="pics/' + employee.picture + '" class="list-icon"/>' +
                  '<p class="line1">' + employee.firstName + ' ' + employee.lastName + '</p>' +
                  '<p class="line2">' + employee.title + '</p>' +
                  '<span class="bubble">' + employee.reportCount + '</span></a></li>');
          });
          setTimeout(function() {
              scroll.refresh();
          });
      });
  }
```

I got the tutorial from here http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/10/sample-app-mobile-jquery-without-jquery-mobile/

Comment: Its displaying the data, so what's the deal?

Comment: I saw your code get json. Probable, issue is serviceURL + 'getemployees.php'. it should serviceURL.

Comment: `$.ajaxError` includes **four** parameters, for some reason you've decided to ignore the most useful one:  `$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError) { alert("Failed: " + thrownError); })` and it will kindly tell you what the actual error is so you can fix it rather than have us take wild guesses.

Comment: i'm getting error code undefined @freedomn-m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vaiable `serviceURL` is set to `"http://orba.com.ng/getemployees.php"`

Your code says this: `$.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getemployees.php',`

So the effective URL is `http://orba.com.ng/getemployees.phpemployees.php`

Which is probably wrong.

Comment: sorry about that, i've edited the question. its not showing